# SwiftUI, Passing a View as params in @Viewbuilder

Tags: ios, struct, swiftui, swift-protocols, viewbuilder

My curiosity takes me to pass a `View` type as parameter to `@ViewBuilder`. Passing a Model/Primitive type as param in `@ViewBuilder` is perfectly valid.

As shown below code.

```
struct TestView<Content: View>: View {
    
    let content: (String) -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (String) -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content("Some text")
    }
}

struct ContentTestView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TestView {
            Text("\($0)")
        }
    }
}
```

In place of `String` in

```
let content: (String) -> Content
```

If I try to pass a SwiftUI `View` type, then Compiler is not happy with it.

```
let content: (View) -> Content
```

Even though params for `@ViewBuilder` accepts custom Protocol type  like `Searchable` but not `View` protocol.

compiler tell me this `Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

My whole idea is that `content` can be allowed to hold `Section/List/Text` in it.

Edit: I expected code like below.

```
struct TestView<Content: View>: View {

    let content: (View) -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (View) -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        content(
            List {
                ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                    Text(\(i))
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

struct ContentTestView: View {

    var body: some View {
        TestView { viewbody -> _ in
            
            Section(header: Text("Header goes here")) {
                viewbody
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any way can I achieve this ?

Comment: Very interesting... before proceed... how would you expect to use it in `TestView { ??? in`, as ??? will be an opaque unknown, for you, view?

Comment: @Asperi updated expected code.

Answer (score 4):

The possible solution is to use `AnyView`, like

```
struct TestView<Content: View>: View {
    
    let content: (AnyView) -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (AnyView) -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content(AnyView(
            Text("Demo")   // << put here any view hierarchy
        ))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It works as expected.

usage of `AnyView` is not recommended (allowed in some situation). I was thinking any better approach.